# Java Simple Json unexpected Token END OF FILE

Tags: java, json, servlets

I'm testing a servlet on my PC, but if I run it I get Unexpected Token end of File at line 24 which is "Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("C:\libs\data.json"));".

```
String id = request.getParameter("id");
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

    FileWriter file;
    file = new FileWriter("C:\\libs\\data.json");

    try{

        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("C:\\libs\\data.json"));
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
        String cont = (String) jsonObject.get(id);
        System.out.println(cont);
        int downloads = Integer.parseInt(cont);
        ++downloads;

        jsonObject.put(id, downloads);

        file.write(jsonObject.toJSONString());
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        file.flush();
        file.close();
    }
```

Comment: I suspect the JSON is invalid then. Unfortunately, we can't see the JSON...

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you create a `FileWriter` to a file, by default, the file is *truncated*. That is, the data is erased and the file has size zero.

Opening a `FileReader` on the file at that point just tries to read an empty file. Hence the end-of-file. Move the creation of the `FileWriter` until after you have read the entire file and closed it.